# Hibernate criteria sum

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

guys thanks for your time and help i have this Mysql SQL

```
SELECT
IFNULL(SUM(IF((P_P LIKE 'P%'), 1, 0)), 0) AS numIn,
IFNULL(SUM(IF((P_A LIKE 'A%'), 1, 0)), 0) AS numOut
FROM PA_DATE
```

i try this on HQL

```
SELECT
COALESCE(SUM(IF((P_P LIKE 'P%'), 1, 0)), 0) AS numIn,
COALESCE(SUM(IF((P_A LIKE 'A%'), 1, 0)), 0) AS numOut
FROM PaDate
```

i get Error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect$3.getReturnType(Dialect.java:102)
```

what i have to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe HQL supports `if()` as a function.  The following should work in both databases:

```
SELECT SUM(case when P_P LIKE 'P%' then 1 else 0 end) AS numIn,
       SUM(case when P_A LIKE 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) AS numOut
FROM PaDate
```

Comment: ok, i see thanks for your time and help o have to use case when for this type of conditions thanks again for your time and help

Comment: One question how i can add a second table in the sum?

Comment: @Chacaman . . . You should ask another question.  It always helps to have sample data and desired results.